# execute cassandra command line from C#

Tags: c#, python, cassandra, cqlsh

I would like to execute a cqlsh copy command from c# source code.  I would like to execute a Python script, which exists under the folowing path:

```
C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\python\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\cqlsh.py
```

That will give me this screenshot:
[image]

Once in cqlsh, I can then run the command "copy emp to emp.csv"
The idea,  is that I would like to execute all this from c# code.  Here is what I did:

```
 try
            {

Process p = new Process(); // create process (i.e., the python program
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Python27\python.exe";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // make sure we can read the output from stdout
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\cqlsh.py" + " " + "-e copy key_space.emp to 'D:/emp.csv'"; // start the python program with two parameters
            p.Start(); // start the process (the python program)
            p.WaitForExit();

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                string strError = ex.Message;
            }
```

There is no exception caught  but also there is nothing happened in term of result.
Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your problem is with this line:

```
bin\cqlsh.py" + " " + "copy emp to D:/emp.csv";
```

If you were to run this from the command line, cqlsh would require the `-e` flag to execute a command.  In Windows it'd look something like this (assuming a keyspace name of "your_keyspace":

```
python bin\cqlsh.py -e "copy your_keyspace.emp to d:\emp.csv"
```

So to actually call that from your process, you would either have to escape the double quotes or just use single quotes:

```
bin\cqlsh.py" + " " + "-e 'copy your_keyspace.emp to d:\emp.csv'";
```

Comment: i did as you said , the error has gone , but i didn't get any result , please adise , thanks

Comment: @MaherHTB Well you're on Windows, so maybe you might have to turn around the slash in the file location?  ex: `d:\emp.csv` vs. `d:/emp.csv`.